# Redisson ERR command is not allowed

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster, redisson

While connecting to Redis using Redisson (3.23.4) getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.redisson.client.RedisException: ERR command is not allowed. channel: [id: 0x7ecad0a8, L:/Redis_IP:51736 - R:Redis_IP/Redis_IP:15000] command: (CLUSTER NODES), promise: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@4b777e86[Not completed, 1 dependents], params: []
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:381)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommand(CommandDecoder.java:205)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:144)
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:120)
```

Redisson config is following:

```
config.useClusterServers()
                .addNodeAddress("rediss://" + redisHost + ":" + redisPort)
                .setUsername(UserName)
                .setPassword(redisPassword)
                .setKeepAlive(true)
                .setRetryAttempts(3)
                .setRetryInterval(3000)
                .setConnectTimeout(15000)
                .setIdleConnectionTimeout(30000)
                .setScanInterval(1000)
                .setPingConnectionInterval(60000)
                .setSslEnableEndpointIdentification(true);
```

Code works fine when connecting to Single Redis node using "useSingleServer"

Redis cluster has single entry point and internally has Master Slave where data is synced between the Nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"useSingleServer" should be used as Redis Enterprise is configired in such away, even with multi-node Redis cluster, End-point behaves same as single node.